# How to Set a Button Value in Javascript for WCAG

Tags: javascript, button

In order to make our website WCAG 2.0 ready all of our buttons need to have a value. One of our buttons however is setup through javascript and I'm not sure how to do so.

This is the code that I think needs to be changed:

te+"IE":"",role:"dialog",tabindex:"-1"}).hide(),g=o(ae,"Overlay").hide(),L=t([o(ae,"LoadingOverlay")[0],o(ae,"LoadingGraphic")[0]]),y=o(ae,"Wrapper"),x=o(ae,"Content").append(S=o(ae,"Title"),M=o(ae,"Current"),K=t('').attr({id:te+"Previous"}),I=t('').attr({id:te+"Next"}),R=o("button","Slideshow"),L),P=t('').attr({id:te+"Close"}),y.append(o(ae).append(o(ae,"TopLeft"),b=o(ae,"TopCenter"),o(ae,"TopRight")),o(ae,!1,"clear:left").append(T=o(ae,"MiddleLeft"),x,C=o(ae,"MiddleRight")),o(ae,!1,"clear:left").append(o(ae,"BottomLeft"),k=o(ae,"BottomCenter"),o(ae,"BottomRight"))).find("div div").css({"float":"left"}),F=o(ae,!1,"position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none"),

Any help is greatly appreciated! I am sadly clueless on JS and Google has been no aid.

Comment: Since when is that a WCAG requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put an

```
.attr('value', 'Your Text')
```

in that chain somewhere.

or try

```
.attr({ value: 'Your Text' })
```

or try adding value to the .attr({id:te+"Close"})

```
.attr({id:te+"Close", value: 'Your text'})
```